# question about size (bytes) of webpage retrieved using erlang

Tags: http, erlang, http-headers

I have got a question about `http:request(...)` in erlang.

When I retrieve a page using the above command (for example the main page of an apache webserver), I have in my headers list the value `{"content-length","177"}`, which seems right, because using byte_size(...) on the body of the page I get the same result..this suggests me that the size of the page is 177 bytes.

I checked this result using `Tools -> page info` option in firefox, but it says that the size is 146 bytes...can you tell me why there is this difference?

Comment: One includes headers and the other does not?

Comment: Maybe content is dynamic or just changed because request from http client is different than from browser?

Comment: i checked the size of the file with an ls -h on shell and it is 177bytes...so i guess i can keep on with my implementation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In The [HTTP specification (RFC 2616) Section 14.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) is the definition of the `content-lenght` header:

> 14.13 Content-Length
>
> The Content-Length entity-header field
>   indicates the size of the entity-body,
>   in decimal number of OCTETs, sent to
>   the recipient or, in the case of the
>   HEAD method, the size of the
>   entity-body that would have been sent
>   had the request been a GET.

So either Firefox is wrong, got a different content or shows the size for a different definition of "size".